# Show 2 sets of all numbers in [0,1] having decimal representation with certain restriction are countable ( or not )?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be the set of all numbers in [0,1] having decimal representation $0.a_1a_2a_3 ...$ where $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$ for all $n\in N$. Show $S$ is countable

And

Let $T$ be the set of all numbers in [0,1] having decimal representation $0.a_1a_2a_3 ...$ where $|a_n - a_{n+1}|\leq 1 $ for all $n\in N$ . Determine if $T$ is countable

For set $S$, every decimal representation will become constant. It will either have a digit other than 9 as its tail, for eg 0.234555555555555555 etc or increase and eventually have 9 as its tail, for eg 0.222555577899999...

This shows we can form a bijection from the set of rational numbers to each decimal representation.

For the second set $T$, $ a_n -1 \leq  a_{n+1}\leq a_n +1 $ , this set doesn't looks countable as it is can form any combination of real number in $[0,1]$. The tail end can range from 0 to 9.

I have a rough understanding but I can't translate my intuition into a formal proof

Comment: Well, there aren't many possibilites for each $\;a_n\;$ , are there? So if you impose the condition $\;a_n\le a_{n+1}\;$ the number's decimal representation will eventually have to be periodic, so you get only rational numbers in this way and...

Comment: @DonAntonio , can l just map rational numbers to this set ? How do l show the decimal representation will be periodic beyond just writing it out in plain English (as done  in my post)

Comment: Begin construction such a number with decimal representation as you want. The first decimal $\;a_1\;$ can be whatever digit you want (including zero), but after you've chosen this digit the next one $\;a_2\;$ must be either the same you've already chosen or one digit **bigger** than $\;a_1\;$ ...after finitely many steps either you've kept the same digits many times or you've chosen some bigger ones ...and you cannot backtrack and choose a smaller digit by your condition $\;a_n\le a_{n+1}\;$ ! Eventually you get a  number with its decimals the very same digit except for a finite number of them

Comment: Notice that a number is rational iff it has a periodic decimal expansion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: There is an injective mapping $f$ from $S$ to $\mathbb{Z}^{9}$. Indeed, for each $x \in S$, define $f$ as follows:

$$f(x)=(n_1(x),n_2(x),\ldots, n_9(x)),$$ where for each $k=1,2,\ldots, 9$, the integer $n_k(x)$ is the smallest integer $n$ such that $a_n=k$ where $a_n$ is the $n$-th digit of $x$ in its decimal expansion. [If the decimal expansion of $x$ terminates with $k$ for some $k<9$ and so the digits $k+1,\ldots, 9$ never appear, then $n_{k'}(x)$ is set to $0$ for each $k'=k+1,\ldots, 9$.]

You can check that $f$ is indeed injective. Then from there, we know that $\mathbb{Z}^9$ is a countable set....

ETA: OR just note that each $x \in S$ is rational. Indeed, let $k$ be the largest digit in $x$'s decimal expansion. Then letting $n_k(x)$ be as above:

$$x=m_x + \frac{k \times 10^{-n_k(x)+1}}{9} \ \text{ if $k <9$ },$$
$$x = m_x + 10^{-n_k(x)+1} \  \text{ if $k = 9$ },$$
where $m_x$ is a finite decimal that goes out only to the $n_k(x)$-th digit.

---

$T$ is uncountable. Indeed, we give a injective mapping $g$ from $[0,1]$ into $T$. Let $Y$ be the set of binary strings of infinite length. Then for each $y \in Y$, let $t=g(y)$ be the number in $T$ where the $k$-th digit $t_k$ of $t$ satisfies:

1. If the $k$-th bit $y_k$ of $y$ is $1$, then $t_k=t_{k-1}+1$ if $t_{k-1} \not = 9$, otherwise $t_k = 8$ [i.e., $t_k=9-1=t_{k-1}-1$].
2. If the $k$-th bit $y_k$ of $y$ is $0$ then $t_k=t_{k-1}$.
3. $t_1 = y_1$.

Check to see for yourself that $g$ is indeed an injective mapping, from all of $Y$ into $T$.

Comment: How about for Set T, should l use diagonal argument to show its uncountable since it resembles the real number set [0,1] ? And thanks for the hint on the first problem

Comment: $T$ is not countable. Find an injective mapping from $[0,1]$, where each number $y \in [0,1]$ is represented by its binary expansion, into $T$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Every one of these numbers has a constant "tail;" i.e for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $n \mapsto d_n$ is constant for $n\ge N$, where $d_n$ is the nth digit in the decimal expansion.  All of these numbers are rational.